# Spring Data REST Bean Validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, rest, spring-data-rest

Consider a `Person` entity with a property `name` that is annotated as `@NotNull`. Then a simple `PersonRepository` and this repo exposed with Spring Data Rest.

When I `POST` to create a new `Person`, if the `name` property is `null` a `ValidationException` occurs as expected. But what I actually get on the client is an *Internal Server Error* (500) and the message is a `TransactionSystemException` that happened much later in the exception chain.

What I'd expect to get is a *Bad Request* (400) with the actual `ValidationException` and all it's useful information so the client can know what's wrong with the posted data.

There seems to be a way to attach custom validators with SDR as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/#validation). But the thing is, this is not a custom validator, it's a standard bean validation that happens when the repository is asked to save data. So I'm not really sure how those two come together.

So questions:

1. What are my options to let the client know what's wrong with the submitted data when using SDR?. Things like what fields are invalid and what's the error for each field would be awesome.
2. Are there any examples about this anywhere?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a proper `ExceptionHandler`, it will handle back end exceptions and send meaningful rich messages (json/xml) to the front end client.

Take a look a this [git repository](https://github.com/jirutka/spring-rest-exception-handler)

Comment: This looks like the correct way to tackle my problem and the linked lib is awesome. Just one thing if I may abuse the question. In my specific case my exception chain looks like this: `ConstraintViolationException` -> `RollbackException` -> `TransactionSystemException`. I would like to target the `ConstraintViolationException`, not the rest of them. So which exception does spring considers: the root exception or the last exception in the chain?

Comment: @user1387786 of course you target the main exception  which is the last exception in chain , in spring Data it would be `DataIntegrityViolationException` or if you are using hibernate directly it would be `ConstraintViolationException`

Comment: Looks like this does not work on SDR because the exceptions are wrapped. https://github.com/jirutka/spring-rest-exception-handler/issues/5.